# Unexpected type cast when pushing key and value into array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have my empty array

```
const arr = [];
```

I want to push 2 things. 1.) a numerical value and 2.) an object

```
data.push('id':id, 'obj':storedObj);
```

This throws `Unexpected type cast`. I was curious if something like this was do-able?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data.push(id, storedObj)`?

Comment: Are you trying to push two things to the array? Shouldn't they be surrounded by braces? `data.push({'id':id, 'obj':storedObj});`

Comment: that won't include the keys @nnnnnn

Comment: @nnnnnn It seems the code is supposed to push an object into the array.

Comment: Array elements don't have string keys, they have numeric indices. You can assign properties with string keys with `data.id = id`, but `.push()` adds an element with the next available numeric index. (Also, shouldn't it be `arr.push()` rather than `data.push()`?)

Comment: @nickn but then thats pushing one big object into an array. rather than id isolated as its own key in the array, and obj as its own key.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data.push({'id': id}, {'obj': storedObj});` ?

Comment: Related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: @nnnnnn you're right, they have numeric indices. I think i meant properties. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add something that looks like a JavaScript object. To add id and storedObj do:

```
data.push(id, storedObj);
```

But if you want to identify each one by the keys, define like this:

```
data = {};
data.id = id;
data.obj = storedObj;
```

And if you want to insert an object do:

`data.push({'id':id, 'obj':storedObj});`

Answer (score 0):

you need to push objects into the array. So do something like this

```
data.push({'id':id}); data.push({'obj':storedObj});
```

You get to keep the keys